# Покрасить весь абзац в WORD

Tags: vba, ms-word, макросы

Всех Приветствую. В общем, нужно сделать `макрос` в `Microsoft Word`. Пользователь ставит курсор в любую часть текста, и абзац, в котором находится курсор выделяется и окрашивается в красный цвет.
Знаю, что с помощью `Selection.Font.TextColor = 200` можно окрасить текст в красный, поэтому решил сначала найти `начало абзаца`:

```
With Selection.Find
 .Forward = False
 .ClearFormatting
 .MatchWholeWord = True
 .MatchCase = False
 .Wrap = wdFindContinue
 .Execute FindText:="^p"
End With
```

А потом идти по тексту, пока не найду конец абзаца.
И вот в этом и заключается проблема - я просто не знаю, как идти по тексту, чтобы выделять каждое попадающееся мне слово.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашёл похожее решение в интернете, чуть исправил, чтобы делало то, что мне требуется:

```
Dim i&, iPos&
    iPos = Selection.Paragraphs(1).Range.Start
    With ActiveDocument
        Do
            i = i + 1
        Loop While .Paragraphs(i).Range.Start - iPos
    End With
    ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(i).Range.Select
Selection.Font.TextColor = wdColorBlue
```